# Unable to install xlrd 1.0.0 wheel

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to install the wheel `xlrd-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl` on a Windows 7 (64-bit) computer with Python v2.7.12 installed.

I get the following error message:

```
xlrd-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel for this platform.
```

I downloaded the wheel from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd which says that the wheel works for python 2.7+
The command I entered in `CMD.EXE` is:

```
python -m pip install  xlrd-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look the error message:

> xlrd-1.0.0-**py3**-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel for this
>   platform.

I might be wrong, but py3 is Python 3. So not Python 2.7.
With Python 2.7+, they maybe mean 2.7.xx+, so that's still Python 3.

Try installing it from here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils#downloads
The py2.py3 version supports Python 2 and Python 3.

Or, maybe even pip will work fine:

```
pip install xlutils
pip install xlrd
```

Comment: Quick Question: when I typed in the cmd  pip install xlutils.... it directly started installing the xlutils and even xlrd. What just happened?? I did not even download the wheel for xlutils....    Even I think py3 is for python 3 so i mentioned all the configuration of my system.

Comment: @Shank is it working now? To answer the question in your comment: Xlrd is needed to run xlutils, so it's automatically included in it's package-installation. Documentation: http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/

Comment: @Shank - "pip install xlutils" installs xlutils from an online repository; your original attempt looked like it was from a downloaded wheel file. I have the same problem as your original one in that I'm trying to install offline; I can't use pip that way.